# Timer calls Timer_Tick event only when the page finishes the execution of entire page

Tags: c#, .net, windows

I have an application in which I am starting a timer for two task:

1. On a single loop having one item.
2. Having more than one item

Now when I have one item then timer starts slide show perfectly but when I have more than one item then I have to loop through it so the timer_tick event is not able to start on a continuous loop.

Is there any option such that I suddenly can start the timer..?

Comment: Please clarify with some code. How does your question relate to the page lifecycle? If you are using ASP.NET then please add the relevant tag.

Comment: What Timer, what kind of 'Page' ?  It's unclear whether this is a Web or Win application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're lacking some more information for a more specific answer, but in case you're talking about a Windows Forms app, all you have to do is calling `Application.DoEvents()` from time to time, to allow other events to be processed (e.g. call it once after each iteration). For other techniques (e.g. WPF or ASP) there are similar approaches.

Answer (score 0):

If you have two independent Timers which both trigger a long running task then maybe you should create a **background worker** (more info: http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx) for the long running task.

Or if you have a long running loop and a short one, use the Application.DoEvents() as stated before.